# Custom groupbox control not painting correctly when added to tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a groupbox which I created a custom paint event for so that I
can control the border color.

It works great when the groupbox is on a form but when the groupbox is
on a tabpage, the control does not paint properly.  Everything is blurry
and the child controls inside the groupbox are also blurry and get a border
drawn.

Any gentle help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Dan

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomGroupBoxPaint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        private void groupBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Default border line color
            Color lineColor = Color.LightGray;

            // Get the control
            GroupBox gb = (GroupBox)sender;

            // Figure out which color to use
            if (gb.Enabled == true)
            {
                // User black line
                lineColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                // Use dark gray color
                lineColor = Color.DarkGray;
            }

            //get the text size in groupbox
            System.Drawing.Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, gb.Text, gb.Font);

            // Draw groupbox border
            Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            borderRect.Y = (borderRect.Y + (tSize.Height / 2));
            borderRect.Height = (borderRect.Height - (tSize.Height / 2));
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, lineColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            // Draw groupbox text
            Rectangle textRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            textRect.X = (textRect.X + 6);
            textRect.Width = tSize.Width + 5;
            textRect.Height = tSize.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(gb.BackColor), textRect);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, gb.Text, gb.Font, textRect, gb.ForeColor);
        }
    }
}

namespace CustomGroupBoxPaint
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.groupBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.checkBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.groupBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.checkBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBox2.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBox3.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBox4.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 24);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(376, 352);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
            this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(368, 326);
            this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // groupBox2
            // 
            this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.checkBox2);
            this.groupBox2.Enabled = false;
            this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52, 168);
            this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
            this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(272, 100);
            this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox2.Text = "DisabledGBTabPage";
            this.groupBox2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox_Paint);
            // 
            // checkBox2
            // 
            this.checkBox2.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 42);
            this.checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2";
            this.checkBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.checkBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.checkBox2.Text = "checkBox2";
            this.checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
            this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(48, 32);
            this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
            this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(272, 100);
            this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox1.Text = "EnabledGBTabPage";
            this.groupBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox_Paint);
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(64, 48);
            this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.checkBox1.Text = "checkBox1";
            this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(368, 326);
            this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tabPage2.Text = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // groupBox3
            // 
            this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.checkBox3);
            this.groupBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(512, 78);
            this.groupBox3.Name = "groupBox3";
            this.groupBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.groupBox3.TabIndex = 1;
            this.groupBox3.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox3.Text = "EnabledGBform";
            this.groupBox3.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox_Paint);
            // 
            // checkBox3
            // 
            this.checkBox3.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 42);
            this.checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3";
            this.checkBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.checkBox3.TabIndex = 1;
            this.checkBox3.Text = "checkBox3";
            this.checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // groupBox4
            // 
            this.groupBox4.Controls.Add(this.checkBox4);
            this.groupBox4.Enabled = false;
            this.groupBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(512, 238);
            this.groupBox4.Name = "groupBox4";
            this.groupBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.groupBox4.TabIndex = 2;
            this.groupBox4.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox4.Text = "DisabledGBform";
            this.groupBox4.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox_Paint);
            // 
            // checkBox4
            // 
            this.checkBox4.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 42);
            this.checkBox4.Name = "checkBox4";
            this.checkBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 17);
            this.checkBox4.TabIndex = 1;
            this.checkBox4.Text = "checkBox4";
            this.checkBox4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
            this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
            this.groupBox3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox3.PerformLayout();
            this.groupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox4.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox4;
    }
}
```

[Screen shot showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcF1R.png)

Comment: Try calling `e.Graphics.Clear(gb.BackColor);` at the start of your paint routine.

Comment: `e.ClipRectangle` is usually always wrong to use.  Use the whole control space.

Comment: @LarsTech The Graphics.Clear was the trick.  Although I was not able to get my example above to work (something seems to go wrong with the background color on the tab control), I was able to get the same solution to work in my application perfectly.  Not sure why they work differently but I'll go with it.  Thank you for your help.